# Launching an interpreted script

Tags: c, security, perl, unix

I was just wondering if this is a good example, following good practices, of a C program for launching an interpreted script from a native binary executable. Here the interpreter is Perl and the script an implementation of something analogous to du --apparent-size, but the idea is general.

Also, is this code secure against potentially hostile users, at least if Perl is the interpreter (for instance, in a suid or sgid program)?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  char* command[argc+3];
  command[0] = "/usr/bin/perl";
  command[1] = "-W";
  command[2] = "-T";
  command[3] = "/home/demetri/bin/awklikeperl.pl";
  for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
    command[i+4] = argv[i+1];
  }
  execv(command[0], command);
  int error = errno;
  fprintf(stderr, "Failed to exec: %s\n", strerror(error));
  if (error == ENOENT) {
    return(127);
  } else {
    return(126);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No it is not safe:

1. Classic off-by-one error. You reserve space for 3 additional entries with `command[argc+3]` but you add 4. `argv[i+1]` and `command[i+4]` will be out of bounds on the last iteration (last valid index is `argv[argc-1]` and `command[argc+2]` respectively)
2. [`execv`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) expects a NULL terminated array of NULL terminated strings. So the last entry in `commands` needs to be NULL (otherwise how would `execv` know how many arguments to pass when starting the process?).

Comment: You are correct about the off by one error. However, argv[argc] is guaranteed to be 0 by the C standard.

Comment: Ah true, it's a NULL terminated list, I forgot

Answer (score 17):

Consider starting the child process in [a sandbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4249063/how-can-i-run-an-untrusted-c-program-in-a-sandbox-in-linux).  `/usr/bin/perl` is likely safe from a malicious user since `/usr/bin` is typically locked down by the root user(s).  But `/home/demetri/bin/awklikeperl.pl` could be replaced if the owner is not careful with permissions.  Putting the process in a sandbox will not only protect the rest of your system from attack, but help you think about what files will be made available.

Obviously, the content of the script should be reviewed for vulnerabilities as well.  Take a look at [`perlsec`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html) for help on that front.

`3` is a bit of a magic number in the C program.  As you've already discovered, it's easy to forget to change that number if you add or subtract parameters from the `command` array.  If you define that in one place (say `#DEFINE STARTING_ARGS 3`) you'll only need to change the value in one place.

Speaking of which, I considered suggesting adding a `--` parameter to prevent any shenanigans with adding extra switches.  But once you pass the script name to perl, it passes all other arguments onto the script.  So I think it's not possible to use `-e` to execute an arbitrary command.

Comment: Where would you put the `--` if you suggested it? The only place it would make sense is immediately *before* the script-to-run (i.e. before `command[3]`) - And, since the path/script name itself is "clean", it won't be interpreted as a perl argument. Having said that, I would actually recommend that you actually do suggest that ;-) - that way a later change to the script that's run - even a dynamic script, possibly, will still work - including if someone were to make their input file `-` or the traditional "use standard in" `cat myperl.pl | perl -W -T -- -`

Comment: If we're relying on [`chroot` to sandbox `perl`](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5334/what-is-sandboxing/5337#5337), it looks like it's not too hard to [break out of it too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7613325/how-to-exit-a-chroot-inside-a-perl-script)...

Comment: You say that the OP should use `#DEFINE STARTING_ARGS 3` but `#DEFINE` does not enforce type safety and is a nightmare when debugging, I suggest `const int STARTING_ARGS = 3` at the start of `main` to overcome these issues.

Answer (score 6):

Your `fprintf()` call can be written more simply using [`perror()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/perror.html):

```
perror("Failed to exec")
```